# PromQL - Count how many times a metric had the same value

Tags: prometheus, promql

Is there any function that shows how many times a specific metric had the same value on Prometheus?

I have a metric that constantly returns the integer 1024:
exec_nsa_server_brokers_on_KM

When something goes wrong, this value could be 1023 or even 1022. What I'd like achieve is to have a query that returns how any times that metric returned 1024 or 1023.

I have tried some of the count functions but looks like they work on different scenarios.

Comment: "How many times" would depend on the scraping interval and supposing no scrape failed or was skipped and supposing no drift occurred and some other conditions. Can you please clarify what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either subqueries or recording rules for that. The subquery version would be something along the lines of:

```
sum_over_time(count_values without() ("value", up)[10m:])
```

(replacing `up` with `exec_nsa_server_brokers_on_KM` in your case; and optionally using `avg_over_time` instead to get a ratio instead of an absolute value).

This would give you an approximation of the number of times each timeseries had a given value over the past 10 minutes (or whatever time range you're interested in).

The recording rule alternative might be more efficient if you're calculating this value often enough (e.g. on a refreshing dashboard) and would consist simply in recording the value of `count_values without() ("value", up)` into a new metric and then calculating `sum_over_time()` / `avg_over_time()` on top of that metric instead.

Comment: I have a case where i insert a record whenever an event occurs(example whenever an IOT device goes offline/online) (not using prometheus scrapper, but ingest data in Victoria metrics on receiving event). So i have data something like 12 o clk - devcon_s = 1, at 3o clk devcon_s = 0, at 4 o clk  devcon_s = 1 etc. I want to count how many times the device disconnected in a day. Do you have any idea how can i do that. ??

Comment: `resets(devcon_s[24h])`? See https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#resets

Answer (score -1):

Prometheus doesn't provide straightforward functions for this task except of subquery hack described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58744742/274937).

This task can be easily solved with Prometheus-like system I work on - VictoriaMetrics. It provides [count_eq_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_eq_over_time) and [count_ne_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_ne_over_time) functions from [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) for counting the number of raw samples matching/mismatching the given value on the given lookbehind window. For example, the following query returns the number of raw samples with 1024 value over the last hour:

```
count_eq_over_time(exec_nsa_server_brokers_on_KM[1h], 1024)
```